# matrix representation of NTRU polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do you express a polynomial $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ with maximum degree n=7, as a polynomial? The polynomial has coefficients of either 0 or 1, so the rest of the terms $x^6, x^5, x^4, x^3$ have 0 coefficients.
How can you write f(x) as a matrix?

In NTRU public key cryptosystem, the system is based on lattices. I would like to find out how these polynomial equations can be transformed to vectors (in a vector space) and written in matrix form.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you cannot write a polynomial "as" a matrix. Nevertheless, there are two usual **correspondences** between polynomials and matrices 1) through characteristic polynomials 2) through "companion matrices" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

You can view your polynomial $p$ as an element of the vector space of polynomials of 7-th degree, $p\in P_7$. In the monomial basis $\mathcal B=\{1,x,\ldots,x^7\}$ it is given by the coordinate vector $[p]_\mathcal B =\begin{bmatrix}1 &1&1&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}^T$